# Django child url does not show its template

Tags: python, regex, django, url

I have two different urls:
1) `/campaigns/`, which lists available campaigns and 2)`campaigns/add/` where there is a form to fill the details of a campaign to be created.

My django `urls.py` file looks like:

```
url(r'^campaigns/', views.campaigns, name='agency-campaigns'),
url(r'^campaigns/add/$', views.add_campaign, name='agency-add-campaign')
```

The problem is that whenever I browse the `/campaigns/` url, it shows the correct template. But when I browse the `/campaigns/add/` url, it still shows the `/campaigns/` url template.

What can be wrong with this subdirectory?
Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you're planning on including any other campaign related urls you may want to consider making a separate app for campaigns

Answer (score 6):

That's because you don't have the end of string match (`$`) at the end of the regular expression:

```
url(r'^campaigns/$', views.campaigns, name='agency-campaigns'),
#            HERE^
```

Or, you can also put the "agency-add-campaign" pattern before the "agency-campaigns":

```
url(r'^campaigns/add/$', views.add_campaign, name='agency-add-campaign'),
url(r'^campaigns/', views.campaigns, name='agency-campaigns')
```